# Setting failover of NAT gateway instances in GCE

Tags: nat, failover, gateway, google-compute-engine

What do people use to update the route-collection when having a NAT gateway compute instance fail?  How do people setup multiple NAT gateways in a region and failover to each other?

Answer (score 2):

One method is configuring multiple (two or more) [NAT gateways](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/special-configurations#natgateway) for your Compute Engine VM instances. When creating routes to send traffic destined to the Internet through your gateway instances (step 5 of [the article](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/special-configurations#natgateway)), specify **the same value** for the **priority** of all these routes. This should setup an automatic failover functionality.

```
gcloud compute routes create no-ip-internet-route --network gce-network \
         --destination-range 0.0.0.0/0 \
         --next-hop-instance nat1-gateway \
         --next-hop-instance-zone us-central1-a \
         --tags no-ip --priority 800


gcloud compute routes create no-ip-internet-route --network gce-network \
         --destination-range 0.0.0.0/0 \
         --next-hop-instance nat2-gateway \
         --next-hop-instance-zone us-central1-f \
         --tags no-ip --priority 800
```

Comment: Has anyone tried this solution and can confirm that it works? Or not?

Comment: Well, it seems to work. I will test further and upvote when I will be sure.

Comment: I got confirmation from "official" Google Support (from a ticket) that this is the right way to go. (I write "official" as Kamran is also from Google Support, but I assume that the above reply is unofficial one.)